# How to identify the bitmap object inside the dalvik in android?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, dalvik

I want to improve the memory management in dalvik, the first step is to find the bitmap objects inside the memory. Do anyone know how to identify a bitmap object when doing the object allocation in dalvik? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this links will be valuable in process of solving issues u have:

http://kohlerm.blogspot.de/2009/07/eclipse-memory-analyzer-10-useful.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html

Cheers